# GCD Finder Algorithm

Tags: c

I wrote a code that finds GCD here,
but it doesn't work.
Where is my mistake?
Can someone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int c(int x, int y);
    
int main()
{
    int x, y;
    printf("Input 1st number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Input 2nd number: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    c(x, y);
    return 0;
}
    
int c(int x, int y)
{
    static int i = 2;
    static int sum = 1;
    if(x == 0 || y == 0) {
        printf("The GCD is: %d", sum);
    }
    else if(x % i == 0 && y % i == 0) {
        x = x / i;
        y = y / i;
        sum = sum * i;
        i++;
        c(x, y);
    }
    else {
        i++;
        c(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you do when you found your code doesn't work? The next step should be to debug it. Run your program in a debugger and trace its flow and variable values. Then update your post with what you find. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Why doesn't your function return a value? And your `static` variables will only be initialised once, so the function can only be used once in the lifetime of the program.

Comment: @kaylum No, the next step is to enable warnings in the compiler and to interpret and resolve each warning.

Comment: I'd recommend you look into for loops. That might be a better starting point for finding the Greatest Common Denominator.

Answer (score 1):

You know what you want and wrote quite a bit of code for it.
On a glance it can be seen that it uses recursion and there seems to be a condition to end the recursion. Looks good.

As hinted in the comments there could be compilation issues. Let's have a look:

```
$ gcc -Wall gcd_original.c
gcd_original.c:34:1: warning: non-void function does not return a value [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
$
```

Some `return` statement missing. Easily fixed, just return `sum` as it seems to become our gcd which is what is to be computed. Its naming could be improved because it is not a sum. Let's call it `gcd`. Now there is no compilation issue anymore.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
    
int c(int x, int y);
    
int main()
{
    int x, y;
    printf("Input 1st number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Input 2nd number: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    c(x, y);
    return 0;
}
    
int c(int x, int y)
{
    static int i = 2;
    static int gcd = 1;
    if(x == 0 || y == 0) {
        printf("The GCD is: %d", gcd);
    }
    else if(x % i == 0 && y % i == 0) {
        x = x / i;
        y = y / i;
        gcd = gcd * i;
        i++;
        c(x, y);
    }
    else {
        i++;
        c(x, y);
    }
    return gcd;
}
```

```
$ gcc -Wall gcd_modified.c
```

No warning. Let's run it:

```
$ ./a.out                         
Input 1st number: 4
Input 2nd number: 6
zsh: segmentation fault  ./a.out
$
```

Oops, what happened? Let's do simple print-debugging, adding **one** line of output:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
    
int c(int x, int y);
    
int main()
{
    int x, y;
    printf("Input 1st number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Input 2nd number: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    c(x, y);
    return 0;
}
    
int c(int x, int y)
{
    static int i = 2;
    static int gcd = 1;
    printf("c: x: %5x, y: %5d, i: %5d, gcd: %5d\n", x, y, i, gcd);  
    if(x == 0 || y == 0) {
        printf("The GCD is: %d", gcd);
    }
    else if(x % i == 0 && y % i == 0) {
        x = x / i;
        y = y / i;
        gcd = gcd * i;
        i++;
        c(x, y);
    }
    else {
        i++;
        c(x, y);
    }
    return gcd;
}
```

And here we go:

```
$ ./a.out
Input 1st number: 4
Input 2nd number: 6
c: x:     4, y:     6, i:     2, gcd:     1
c: x:     2, y:     3, i:     3, gcd:     2
c: x:     2, y:     3, i:     4, gcd:     2
c: x:     2, y:     3, i:     5, gcd:     2
c: x:     2, y:     3, i:     6, gcd:     2
c: x:     2, y:     3, i:     7, gcd:     2
c: x:     2, y:     3, i:     8, gcd:     2
c: x:     2, y:     3, i:     9, gcd:     2
c: x:     2, y:     3, i:    10, gcd:     2
c: x:     2, y:     3, i:    11, gcd:     2
c: x:     2, y:     3, i:    12, gcd:     2
...
c: x:     2, y:     3, i: 130744, gcd:     2
c: x:     2, y:     3, i: 130745, gcd:     2
c: x:     2, y:     3, i: 130746, gcd:     2
c: x:     2, y:     3, i: 130747, gcd:     2
c: x:     2, y:     3, i: 130748, gcd:     2
c: x:     2, y:     3, i: 130749, gcd:     2
zsh: segmentation fault  ./a.out
$
```

Although the gcd is properly calculated the termination does not work. We are already done when `i` becomes bigger than the remaining `x` or `y`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
    
int c(int x, int y);
    
int main()
{
    int x, y;
    printf("Input 1st number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Input 2nd number: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    c(x, y);
    return 0;
}
    
int c(int x, int y)
{
    static int i = 2;
    static int gcd = 1;
    printf("c: x: %5x, y: %5d, i: %5d, gcd: %5d\n", x, y, i, gcd);  
    if(x == 0 || y == 0 || i > x || i > y) {
        printf("The GCD is: %d\n", gcd);
    }
    else if(x % i == 0 && y % i == 0) {
        x = x / i;
        y = y / i;
        gcd = gcd * i;
        i++;
        c(x, y);
    }
    else {
        i++;
        c(x, y);
    }
    return gcd;
}
```

Check

```c
$ gcc -Wall gcd_modified.c
$ ./a.out                 
Input 1st number: 4
Input 2nd number: 6
c: x:     4, y:     6, i:     2, gcd:     1
c: x:     2, y:     3, i:     3, gcd:     2
The GCD is: 2
$
```